# Finding rows with highest means in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, filtering, identity-column

I am trying to find the rows, in a very large dataframe, with the highest mean.

Reason: I scan something with laser trackers and used a "higher" point as reference to where the scan starts. I am trying to find the object placed, through out my data.

I have calculated the mean of each row with:

```
base = df.mean(axis=1)
base.columns = ['index','Mean']
```

Here is an example of the mean for each row:

```
0       4.407498
1       4.463597
2       4.611886
3       4.710751
4       4.742491
5       4.580945
```

This seems to work fine, except that it adds an index column, and gives out columns with an index of type float64. 
I then tried this to locate the rows with highest mean:

```
moy = base.loc[base.reset_index().groupby(['index'])['Mean'].idxmax()]
```

This gives out tis :

```
 index      Mean
0         0  4.407498
1         1  4.463597
2         2  4.611886
3         3  4.710751
4         4  4.742491
5         5  4.580945
```

But it only re-index (I have now 3 columns instead of two) and does nothing else. It still shows all rows.

Comment: I think a sample of the output, and a sample of the input would be a bit critical here to answer your question. But it sounds like you have defined your own index, and mean column (based on other columns in your previous df) and now have a 3rd colummn, maybe the created index of the dataframe created.

Comment: Yes the new column is (second index) is probably from the creation of the new dataframe.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html I would use this

Comment: I can't seem to be able to manually index 'base', it says : 
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'
When i use : 
    base.set_index('index')

Comment: Your dataset is a series, and you need to split the column mean into two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way without using `groupby`

```
moy=base.sort_values('Mean').tail(1)
```

Comment: This works just fine! Would ou know how to have more then 1 row? Right now, it shows me row #319 only, I would need some more.

Comment: @Mat17 tail(n) n is the row you need

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though  your data is a string or single column with a space in between your two numbers. Suggest splitting the column into two and/or using something similar to below to set the index to your specific column of interest.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('testdata.txt', names=["Index", "Mean"], delimiter="\s+")
df = df.set_index("Index")
print(df)
```

Comment: I don't see the point of seperating the column, i would loose the index numbers right?

Comment: The index stays associated with the column

Comment: Think of it like the numbers on the side of an excel spreadsheet. You can set those as well to be unique specific numbers. You can also merge it back with the original df based on that set of values.

Comment: I'll give it a try! Thanks :)